# How to append a new record as a seperate line instead of appending it in a same line

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5fbo72rm/17/

When i run this above js fiddle  how can i append a new row as a seperate line instead of appending it in a same line

```
var dataSet = [
    [
        "1441.75",
        "34444444"],
    [
        "1614.45",
        "34444444"

    ],
    [
        "834.15",
        "233333"]

];

var array_names = ["APPLE", "WHIRLPOOL", "SAMSUNG"];

for (var key in dataSet) {
    if (dataSet.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        dataSet[key].splice(0, 0, array_names[key]);
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#allwl').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "data": dataSet,
            "columns": [{
            "title": "Name"
        }, {
            "title": "Price"
        }, {
            "title": "Quantity"
        }]
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#allwl tr').each(function() {
    var abc = $(this).children('td').eq(2).html();
        if(abc > 40000) {
            $(this).children('td').eq(0).css('background-color', 'green');

            $("#greaterquan").append($(this).html());

        }

});
});
```

Could anybody please let me know how to resolve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/5fbo72rm/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the html content of the `tr` elemnets, which are the `td`s to the table so they are added to the same `tr`... instead append the html of the `tr` which can be obtained by using `this.outerHTML`

```
    if(abc > 40000) {
        $(this).children('td').eq(0).css('background-color', 'green');
        $("#greaterquan").append(this.outerHTML);
    }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b4j852uq/)

---

Another option is to clone the `tr` like

```
$("#greaterquan").append($(this).clone());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b4j852uq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following line:

```
$("#greaterquan").append($("<tr/>").append($(this).html()));
```

instead of:

```
$("#greaterquan").append($(this).html());
```

The reason is you add only `td` tags and forget to add `tr`.